# How would I plot the theoretical normal distribution given an estimate of the mean and variance of a variable?

Tags: r, plot, normal-distribution

I am trying to figure this out. Assuming the variable mile is sampled from a population which is normally distributed, how would I plot the theoretical normal distribution given an estimate of the mean and variance?

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
data

   name    mile
1  dat1    5039
2  dat1    2883
3  dat2    135
4  dat2    104
5  dat3    32
6  dat3    192
```

I have got the mean and variance calculated for mile as below:

```
mean(data$mile)
[1] 1397.5

var(data$mile)
[1] 4410420
```

But I am unsure if this is what is even asked. Has anyone had any dealings with a question like this before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

```
pdf_norm <- function(x,mu,sigma){
  1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2))*exp(-(x - mu)^2/(2*sigma^2))
}

mu <- 1397.5
sigma <- 4410420
x <- seq(mu-3*sigma, mu+3*sigma,length.out = 100) # empirical rule 3 sigma rule
d <- pdf_norm(x, mu,sigma)

plot(x,d, xlab = "X", ylab = "density")
```

To here I get the output of ...

[image: Theoretical Normal Distribution]

I have tried using the code below to superimpose a histogram onto to the above plot...

```
hist(data$mile, add = T)
```

But this results as ...

[image: Superimposing a histogram]

Which obviously isn't right. Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? PDF? CDF?

Comment: @slava-kohut a theoretical distribution i.e. something like a bell curve or probability plot using the mean and variance estimate. I would like to then compare this to an original histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to plot the theoretical distribution, you need to define its PDF first (for example, you can find the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)):

```
pdf_norm <- function(x,mu,sigma){
  1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2))*exp(-(x - mu)^2/(2*sigma^2))
}
```

Here, `x` is the random variable, `mu` is the mean, and `sigma` is the standard deviation.

After that, you can proceed to plotting. Set `mu` and `sigma` to your estimates and evaluate the PDF. The range is chosen using the [three-sigma rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).

```
mu <- 1397.5
sigma <- 4410420
x <- seq(mu-3*sigma, mu+3*sigma,length.out = 100) # empirical rule 3 sigma rule
d <- pdf_norm(x, mu,sigma)

plot(x,d, xlab = "X", ylab = "density")
```

You can also make sure that the PDF approximately integrates to 1:

```
integrate(function(x) pdf_norm(x, mu, sigma), mu-3*sigma, mu+3*sigma)
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @slava-kohut! Could you possibly add a few more comments in explaining what you did. For example, what the x, mu, sigma arguments are and how they are used in the function. Also, how would I plot the estimate mean and variance for the available data from this then?

Comment: Done. You can use `abline` to add straight lines to plot.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extra comments @slava-kohut! Also, if I am looking at the number of observations lets say 200 do I just replace the 100 in the line `seq(mu-3*sigma, mu+3*sigma,length.out = 100)`?

Comment: Are you referring to the sample size? `x <- seq(mu-3*sigma, mu+3*sigma,length.out = 100)` is needed to produce the plot, it can be of any reasonable (large) size. If you want to compare this plot to histogram, you can use it as is and superimpose a histogram.

Comment: Could you provide some example of superimpose a histogram @slava-kohut if possible? That would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rnorm()` function to generate random values from a normal distribution with a given population mean and standard deviation, and then use the `density()` function and `plot()` function to create a normal distribution graph.  Using your data, you could do something like the following:

```
plot(density(rnorm(n = 100000, mean = mean(data$mile), sd = sd(data$mile))))
```

I used the `sd()` function to get the standard deviation but you can also use the square root of the variance: `sqrt(var(data$mile))`

Comment: This is a sample distribution (though very close to the theoretical). This is not what the OP asked for.